# How to get link settings in flux link wizard

Tags: typo3, fluid

I am using the flux link wizard in a fluidcontent element (https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Wizard/LinkViewHelper.html)

like this:

```
<flux:field.input name="link" label="Link">
   <flux:wizard.link />
</flux:field.input>
```

But the rte settings are not invoked in the link wizard (default classes etc.).
Is it possible to add the default rte settings to the flux link wizard?

I am using
TYPO3 8.7.4 with ckeditor
Flux 8.2.1
fluidcontent 5.2.0
fluidpages 4.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PageTSConfig` is [not available](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/pull/1438#issuecomment-318093799) in Fluid templates, which is why it's currently not possible to fetch those settings.